# Laravel 5 - potential bug in extended templates (@yield, @extends)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Just noticed strange behavior of extended views in Laravel 5. It seems like a bug in Laravel and I prepared simple code so you can easily reproduce it:

**Controller:**

```php
$items = [
    ['id' => 1],
    ['id' => 2],
];

return view('list', [
    'items' => $items
]);
```

**list.blade.php:**

```blade
@foreach ($items as $item)
  @include('single-extended', $item)
@endforeach
```

**single.blade.php:**

```blade
<div>id: {{ $id }}</div>

@yield('block')
```

**single-extended.blade.php:**

```blade
@extends('single')

@section('block')
  <div>id in extended: {{ $id }}</div>
@endsection
```

Current output:

```
id: 1
id in extended: 1
id: 2
id in extended: 1
```

Expected output:

```
id: 1
id in extended: 1
id: 2
id in extended: 2
```

Is it a bug or I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `@overwrite` instead of `@endsection` (which is by the way [deprecated](http://wiki.laravel.io/Changelog_%28Laravel_4%29#Blade_Templating) since Laravel 3 - you should use `@stop` in basic cases).

Comment: didn't know ``@endsection`` is deprecated, thx! Just tried ``@stop``, same result.

Comment: [This comment](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1058#issuecomment-17194530) on a Github issue suggests trying to use `@overwrite` instead. Can you try it?

Comment: you are my hero, it works! amend your answer so I can accept it.